# Statistic Shopware 6 versions

Tags: statistics, versioning, shopware, shopware6, reproducible-research

Is there a chart/statistic which versions of Shopware 6 are used by online shops actually.

Background: developing custom plugins, it's hard to cover all versions from 6.1 - current (6.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest supporting the releases since the latest major release `6.4`, which has first been released 1 1/2 years ago. That's ample time for users to have updated to one of the minor releases since then. When you offer plugins in the community store you'll get an overview which Shopware versions your plugin is used with. Looking at the data of my plugins I can tell you that the vast majority is now at `6.4`. Without breaking changes it should not be a problem supporting all `6.4` releases and with the `6.5` major release coming next year you should be able to cover a significant userbase by supporting both the upcoming and the current major release.

Comment: thx for reply. But i keep in doubts. First: you are apointed the releasing date 1,5 year ago, meanwhile 6.1.* has a history of only less than 3 years. At the point of view for users without developer background, a simple update by recommendation within the admin panel has as result obvousily broken functionallaty of plugins. So it is posible,  users decline updates. Second: reading the contract for manufacturer 1.3.3, as i understand, the base for successfully publishing, the plugin must be compatible in every minor version inside the range of mayor version (e.g. 6.*.*).

Comment: Well `6.4` IS the major version. So yes, within that range you should support every minor release, which really shouldn't be an issue because breaking changes are reserved for major releases. I have some data to back up my claim, but I'm not sure if I'm authorized to share that data. If you want more information contact the sales department of Shopware.

Comment: Ok, i get it, thx